# I am having trouble displaying the necessary data. A few authors are omitted since they have not published a book

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to show all authors and how many books they have published, however the below query omits the authors with no books published

SELECT INITCAP(fname), INITCAP(lname), COUNT(*)
FROM author 
JOIN bookauthor USING (authorid)
GROUP BY INITCAP(fname), INITCAP(lname);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use aggregate function you need to add non-aggregate  colnums in `group by`

So add `group by` on `INITCAP(fname), INITCAP(lname)`

```
SELECT INITCAP(fname), INITCAP(lname), COUNT(*)
FROM author 
JOIN bookauthor USING (authorid)
GROUP BY INITCAP(fname), INITCAP(lname)
```

Comment: do you know why this query would be excluding names that have a null value in the field being counted?